# Vaadin-spring autowired

Tags: spring, vaadin, autowired, vaadin7, spring-annotations

I have a vaadin project and I need to use the @Autowired Spring annotation. So I use the vaadin-spring add-on

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
   <artifactId>vaadin-spring</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, if I define autowired class in UI class, it works correctly. But if I define autowired class in another class, this class is always null. For example in this case "serv" is always null.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ProfileWindow extends Window {

    @Autowired
    private Servizio serv;

    ...
    ...

    private Component buildFooter() {
        HorizontalLayout footer = new HorizontalLayout();
        footer.addStyleName(ValoTheme.WINDOW_BOTTOM_TOOLBAR);
        footer.setWidth(100.0f, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

        Button ok = new Button("OK");
        ok.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_PRIMARY);
        ok.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Dati dd = new Dati(Double.parseDouble(nomeField.getValue()), Double.parseDouble(cognomeField.getValue()));

                String out = serv.converti(dd);

                Notification success = new Notification(out);
                success.setDelayMsec(2000);
                success.setStyleName("bar success small");
                success.setPosition(Position.BOTTOM_CENTER);
                success.show(Page.getCurrent());

                BsciEventBus.post(new ProfileUpdatedEvent());
                close();


            }
        });
        ok.focus();
        footer.addComponent(annulla);
        footer.setComponentAlignment(annulla, Alignment.TOP_LEFT);
        footer.addComponent(ok);
        footer.setComponentAlignment(ok, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);

        return footer;
    }   
}
```

ServizioImpl.java

```
@SpringComponent
public class ServizioImpl implements Servizio {

    @Override
    public String converti(Dati dati) {

        //implementation...
        return "out";
    }

}
```

Can you help me to use the autowired annotataion?

Do you have some example code to suggest? I don't understand how solve this problem. 
If I use @SpringComponent on my ProfileWindow, the autowired annotation doesn't work yet.

Thanks

Comment: Spring can autowire fields only in objects it creates. It has no way of knowing that you have *manually* created a new instance. Thus `ProfileWindow` must also be a Spring component and you have to obtain its instance from the Spring context, in order for its fields to be autowired with instances of other components.

Comment: Sorry, but if I use @SpringComponent on `ProfileWindows` the autowired doesn't work. Is there a way to define the Servizio bean in some place so that it can be called by whatever class? I would register it in a applicationContext.xml

Comment: It would be difficult (not impossible) to make the service bean *globally* available, but it may not be the right thing to do. Show some code after the changes to `ProfileWindow`. How are you obtaining an instance? Are you using the autowired field in the constructor? (P.S. welcome to SO, when replying to someone's comment you can use @username so they get notified of your response)

Answer (score 0):

If your class has an injected member, make sure the class itself is instantiated from the ApplicationContext. You can for example create the instance with `context.getBean(ProfileWindow.class)`, or the class instance itself is an annotated member of a managed class. If you instantiate your `ProfileWindow` class with `new` then the injection mechanism doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, but I solved the problem using vaadin spring integration add-on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.xpoft.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-vaadin-integration</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```